# Reverse the tag synonym and make [py.test] a synonym of [pytest]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Currently, [pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytest) is a synonym of [py.test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py.test). But actually the framework is named `pytest` (no space, no capitalization, no punctuation), [as can be seen on the official site](https://pytest.org/). So it would make more sense to make the punctuated tag a synonym of the non-punctuated one, which effectively reverses the current synonymization.